# How am I supposed to form the sentence given below? Can someone help me with it?

Tags: sentence-construction, questions

> - Why my new year has to go exactly opposite to what I have planned?
> - Why does my new year have to go exactly opposite to what I have
>   planned?

Which is the correct sentence?

Comment: In main clause interrogatives, if the interrogative word is not the subject its placement in this position triggers subject-auxiliary inversion, as in your second example.

Answer (score 1):

The second is the correct form.

The most frequent form of a question in English is to precede the subject with some form of the auxiliary verb “do” and follow the subject with the remainder of the verb

Statement

> The girl studied algebra last year

Question

> Did the girl study algebra last year?

“Why” is most often used as an interrogative to initiate a question on purpose or cause. But the resulting question still takes the form appropriate to a question.

Answer (score 0):

> [1] *Why my new year has to go exactly opposite to what I have planned?*
>
> [2] *Why does my new year have to go exactly opposite to what I have*
> *planned?*

In main clause interrogatives, if the interrogative word is not the subject its placement in this position triggers subject-auxiliary inversion, as in [2].

[1] is not ungrammatical, but it is not an interrogative; rather, it is the kind of sentence one might find used as the title of something, perhaps a newspaper headline.

Answer (score 0):

Both are oddly phrased sentences to a native speaker (American). The meaning could easily be confused.

There's something strange about the tense to me. I would phrase it:

> Why would my new year go exactly opposite to what I planned?

or

> Will my new year go exactly opposite to what I planned?